# redirect request for file download to a template first

Tags: htaccess

I need to log downloads to the database, to do this I'm trying to redirect requests for downloads to a template where I can call a custom module function and save info to the db, before providing the original download.

I have the following htaccess, but it just keeps appending to the URL and gives a ';Error: The URL contains too many segments.' error:

```
RewriteRule ^/downloads/files/(.*)\.zip$ /index.php/log/file_downloads/$1 [L]        

# Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This must be pretty close, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I got it! I think at least some if the problems i had testing various versions of this were down to FF caching

RewriteRule /downloads/files/(.*).zip /index.php/log/file_downloads/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

There are two add-ons available for tracking downloads, so I'd suggest investigating these options before trying to roll your own. They are [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) and [Protected Links](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/protected-links) both are quite similar and work very well for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks, but not an option unfortunately. Most of the code required is already in place, it's just the htaccess that I'm having a problem with.